# Can you adapt a 16" bike frame for a 6'2" person with a longer stem?

Tags: bike-fit, tall

I am riding a bike which is not well fit to my body. I believe it has a 16" frame and I have to awkwardly hunch my back to hold the handlebars. Is it standard to get a longer and higher stem for the handlebars to fix this situation, or to do something else?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Offhand that seems far too small, if my mental conversion to metric (c.40cm) is correct.  I'm guessing this must be a mountain bike, since the size is given in inches instead of cm, but it would help if you included more detail about your bike, how you intend to use it and your preferred riding posture.

Answer (score 2):

You could drop more money into this to make it "better" without really fixing it, or you could find a better sized bike.  The main problem with adding size via add-ons is that the frame is still small, and you've now got longer levers poking out.

I have done exactly that on multiple bikes, and ended up bending three seat posts, and cracking three other frames at the post hole area.

Reinforcing the seat post simply makes something else break instead.  Same goes for longer stems or steerer extensions -(though I've personally never bent anything at the front end)

As a fellow tall rider, look for any large-framed bike, they're surprisingly hard to find.  You might consider another style (a MTB or a Road bike) just to get the size needed.

MTBs tend to be small/med/large, whereas road bikes can vary in 2 or 3 cm intervals, or half or one-inch increments.   Just try the largest frame size you can get hold of and see how that feels to ride.

To expand on that, do try and get a test ride before buying a bike.  Even if you don't want it, riding a couple of larger bikes will give you an idea what  the differences are.